# Left Aligning Org-mode MathJax in HTML Export

Tags: org-mode, mathjax

I customized my org file as follows;
    `#+HTML_MATHJAX: align: left mathml: t indent: 5em tagside: left font: Neo-Euler`

This is the sample customization from Org manual. Still I get centered Latex output in my browser, using Microsoft Edge. Chrome does not show Latex output at all. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux (Fedora 22), both Firefox and Chrome behave as expected with the the above fragment. I'm not sure why Chrome on Windows would misbehave, but my suggestion would be to look at the produced HTML file (and possibly change some of the options and see how it changes) and see if that provides any clues (perhaps because your setup is not complete or correct - e.g. where do you get MathJax from?) I can't say anything about what MS Edge does: never used it, never will (most probably).

If you can, you might want to copy the file to a Linux machine and try to view it there (or copy it to an HTTP server and view it from anywhere): if you have trouble with all browsers, the HTML file is probably incorrect.If only some browsers show problematic behavior, they are probably buggy.